# difference between -lgcc_s and gcc

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, linker, loader

what is the difference between linking against `gcc_s` and `gcc` by means of `LDFLAGS`?

Is `gcc_s` a static library and `gcc` shared library?

Because I was looking for a solution where it is mentioned to link against `gcc` whereas only `gcc_s` works in my case. I wish to know the real difference.

```
<<hidden symbol `__name_here' in /some/library/path.a(_filename.o) is referenced by DSO
```

In this case, the problem is usually solved by adding either "-l gcc" or "`gcc -print-libgcc-file-name`" to the linking flags (LDFLAGS). However, unlike my other regular platforms (i386, amd64, sparc64) here it wasn't enough. After a lot of head-banging (to be fair, it also comes from the music) I realized that this flag is necessary both when linking the libc *and*  the final executable file. 
link: http://people.defora.org/~khorben/200903.html

Comment: There is also `libgcc_eh.a`, which gets used when `-static` used. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763394/how-to-build-a-c-program-using-a-custom-version-of-glibc-and-static-linking

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`libgcc_s.so` is a shared library, `libgcc.a` is a static library. They are not equivalent; it may be necessary to link both. libgcc_s contains global variables which must not have multiple copies in a process; the code in libgcc is safe to link multiple times.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, <<it may be necessary to link both. When this necessity will arise?

Comment: @kumar: Some symbols (e.g. `__register_frame`) are only in libgcc_s, others (e.g. `__eprintf`) are only in libgcc. Use `nm -D --defined-only libgcc_s.so` resp. `nm --defined-only libgcc.a` to get full lists to compare.

Comment: Why do we need both? Why are they not the same, only one static and the other dynamic?

Comment: I would assume its a question of size and portability with regards to distribution methods and compliance of code/execution. Whatever useless removed means lighter files, packages, execution (possibly?) and easier debugging/forensics (i assume, from past experiences)