# Difference between libgcc.a and libgcc_s.a?

Tags: c, gcc, aix

We have installed GCC and `libgcc` on AIX 6.1 using the RPM files.

**What I would like to know is why "libgcc_s.a" was not created under the following folder?**

```
/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/
```

There is a `libgcc.a` in that folder but not `libgcc_s.a` and the linker seems to want that libgcc_s.a file there

Reason I ask is if I try create a simple "hello world" type shared lib on AIX 6.1 it complains and says someting like `"cannot find libgcc_s.a"`.

I have run a command like:

```
find / -name '*libgcc*' -print 2>/dev/null
```

to try find libgcc_s.a on tha machine but there is nothing ;-(

Any idea how I can get `libgcc_s.a` onto the AIX machine?

Comment: It seems that `libgcc_s.a` does not exist: only the shared version does: `libgcc_s.so`. Same for `libgcc.a`, which only exists in static version. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547384/difference-between-lgcc-s-and-gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try to compile using the option `-static-libgcc`.

Comment: Hi there, i did that on my C library but now it says undefined symbol: .main any ideas?

Comment: @Lynton Grice: So at least you are one step further now ... ;-) - which other options did you use? A lib normally has no main() hasn't it?

Comment: How can one achieve the effect of `-static-libgcc` without using `-static-libccc`? I have tired `gcc hello.c libc.a libgcc.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lc -lgcc` but it says "cannot file -lgcc_s".

Comment: @Zboson: I say you cannot. Any background on why you want to "switch on the light without using the switch to do do"?

Comment: oppps, I mean I think I can do it by doing `gcc -c hello.c` and then using `ln ...` I just need to figure out the ... now.

Comment: How should `ln` help here? You meant `ld`? @Zboson

Comment: sorry, yeah, I mean `ld`.

Comment: Something like `ld -o hello libgcc.a libc.a hello.o`. But that does not work.

Comment: You are on AIX? @Zboson

Comment: No, why do you ask? I'm just trying to understand the gears in the blackbox.

Comment: Because this question referred to gcc **on AIX**. You might liek to consider asking your own question on your specific problem. @Zboson

Comment: Yes,that's what I'll have to do though I think AIX is a red herring here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may want to build gcc with --enable-shared option.