# linker - use own stdlib implementation

Tags: gcc, linker, std, ld, linker-scripts

I have a problem. Requirement for the project is that we cannot link our app with standard library ( so -nostdlib is on in gcc).

*my_stdlib.c* contains implementation of all functions ***my_memset***, **my_memcpy** ... but linker needs **memcpy** to copy structs

```
MyStruct struct = my_struct;
```

and is complaining about "undefined reference to `**memcpy**'", which is of course correct.

Is it possible to remap ***memcpy*** to ***my_memcpy*** using linker script, parameters passed to **ld** or other way, so linker can use our implementation to copy structs?

Probably ***-wrap,function*** could help but I cannot change **my_memcpy** to **__wrap_memcpy**.

Comment: Why can't you name your functions memcpy, memset etc?

Comment: that is the requirement, all functions needs to be prefixed

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: Anyway, beyond the obvious question why your are restricted in this way you can create a linker script that uses `PROVIDE` to create aliases for symbols (including functions). So you can add lines like `PROVIDE(memset = my_memset);` , `PROVIDE(memcpy = my_memcpy);` etc.

Comment: the other thing you can do is create a wrapper function in _C_ called `memcpy` that calls `my_memcpy`.

Comment: What version of gcc are you using that invokes `memcpy` internally to copy structs? Please post a [mcve] showing this.

Comment: @MikeKinghan : gcc 4.5 with Ubuntu 11.04 will produce these results.

Answer (score 1):

At the GCC level, you can redirect the `memcpy` symbol to a different symbol using:

```
void *memcpy (void *, const void *, size_t) __asm__ ("my_memcpy");
```

This will apply to internally-generated `memcpy` calls, too.  (With GCC.  I think it does not change the internal call sites with Clang.)

Comment: Other interesting things beyond OPs scope: complie your own glibc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763394/how-to-build-a-c-program-using-a-custom-version-of-glibc-and-static-linking and Newlib https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/223929/c-standard-libraries-on-bare-metal/223931

Answer (score 0):

compile with `-fno-builtin`. This should avoid it.

Comment: If you compile with `-fno-builtin` that will not solve the issue. No builtin will still allow the compiler to generate the non builtin form which may be a call to an external `memcpy`. The OP would still have to map `memcpy` to `my_memcpy` routine.

Comment: Don't think so. If this is indeed the case, I would consider it a bug (which might be avoided with `-ffreestanding`, but this might cause other issues).

Comment: At a glance, I didn't find any `libgcc` (for a host of usual and unusual platforms I have available) that would provide it's own `memcpy()` function.